# Getting dynamic execution traces for running a program in QEMU

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, riscv, kvm

I am running Fedora in QEMU for RISC-V ISA (64 bit). I have queries with regards to getting the dynamic execution traces as shown [here](https://static.linaro.org/connect/yvr18/presentations/yvr18-118.pdf)(slide 3.3). This is my boot script for initialing QEMU:

```
qemu-system-riscv64 -d cpu -D \
   -nographic \
   -machine virt \
   -smp 4 \
   -m 4G \
   -kernel <path to elf file> \
   -bios none \
   -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 \
   -device virtio-rng-device,rng=rng0 \
   -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 \
   -drive file=<path to raw file>,format=raw,id=hd0 \
   -device virtio-net-device,netdev=usernet \
   -netdev user,id=usernet,hostfwd=tcp::10000-:22 \
```

I see in the slide to use the `-d` argument when launching the VM, but it does not seem to work. QEMU does not boot and it is hung on the loading stage itself. Is there something that I am missing? Or is there some other way in order to get the dynamic execution traces using QEMU? I do one other question here, but I cannot go past this. Any help would be appreciated.
p.s. Let us just assume that I want to get the traces for a simple hello world C program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-D` option takes a filename to write the traces to, and you have not provided it with one. The rest of your command line will then be being mis-interpreted, because `-nographic` is being taken as the filename.

You should also note that debug tracing of `cpu` events like this will slow QEMU down a lot, so it will generally only be useful for testing relatively small bare-metal ELF binaries. Tracing, for example, a full Linux kernel boot, will take too long and produce too much trace output.

Comment: That helps a lot! I did add a URL for the traces, and indeed, with the cpu flag it slows down a lot, along with the thousands of logs. Is there any way I could only trace the execution of the hello.c binary? I am asking this because I have complied the hello.c file inside the QEMU environment (for it being complied for RISC-V) and will not be passing it as an argument from the startup script. Sorry, if this is a basic question! I am just a beginner in KVMs.